# Advanced F&R Regex - Sheets / Excel - If "X" is in cell A1 and add "Y" to cell B1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, regex, find-and-replace, google-spreadsheets

I am looking for a formula or regex that I can use to find a value in a string in one cell and if found add another string to the adjacent cell in another column.

For example, I have a list of expenses listed in *Col A* by merchant:

- Nandos
- Uber
- McDonalds
- PureGym

I want to categorise these in *Col B* :

```
[ Find "Nandos|McD " in ColA and write "Food" in the equivalent cell in ColB ]

[ Find "Uber" in ColA and write "Travel" in the equivalent cell in ColB ]

[ Find "PureGym" in ColA and write "Gym" in the equivalent cell in ColB ]
```

So I end up with:

- Nandos - Food
- Uber - Travel
- McDonalds - Food
- PureGym - Gym

Comment: The typical way to do this is to create a lookup table with the merchants and their category.  In col B, you would use VLOOKUP or INDEX+MATCH to look up the merchant in the table and return the category.

Comment: Sounds like it would work for sure, can you give me more explicit instructions, I'm a relative beginner :)

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  I posted an answer for you, but just a heads up, the site encourages people to do a little research before asking questions.  Questions that are basically, "This is what I need; do the work for me and hand me an answer", aren't well-received.  You'll typically get comments like, "What have you tried" or "Super User isn't a free coding service".  So you'll know for next time.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Lookup functions, like VLOOKUP or the combination of INDEX and MATCH, are very common, basic functions used in Excel, so it's worth getting familiar with them.  To get you started, there's a good explanation of VLOOKUP [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function).

Here's the gist using your example:

[image]

Some made-up data is in columns A and C.  In another spot on the worksheet, or another worksheet, you have the lookup table.  I stuck it in columns F and G.  Column B is where you want to fill in the category for each entry.  The formula in B2 is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$F$2:$G$5,2,0)
```

You just copy it as needed.  The reference to the merchant in column A isn't anchored, so that will reflect the current row when you copy the formula down the page.  The lookup table in F:G is anchored with absolute addressing (the dollar signs), so it will continue to point to the table when you copy the formula.  The third parameter tells VLOOKUP to retrieve the result from the second column of the table.  The last parameter (`0` or `false`), tells VLOOKUP to do an exact match on the merchant name.

**Enhanced Solution**

You presented a challenge in your comment, suppose the merchant entry in column A is a random text string that contains the merchant name in the lookup table.  You could do that with something like this:

[image]

In row 6, I added the example in your comment.  I also added sequential numbers for the table rows next to the merchant name in the lookup table.  The formula in column B (shown for B6 in the formula window):

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$5,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2:$F$5,A6))*$E$2:$E$5))
```

This uses INDEX to pull the category from column G based on the table row produced by the SUMPRODUCT.

SUMPRODUCT lets you do array operations on a range.  It uses the SEARCH function to see if each merchant name in column F is contained in the merchant string in column A.  Search returns a position or an error, but we're only interested in whether it's there, which would be a numerical result.  ISNUMBER returns a `1` for true or `0` for false, which is multiplied by the table row number added in column E.  The result of the SUMPRODUCT will be the table row of the matching merchant.

If you want to make the merchant name more visible, you could insert a column to the right of A to display just the merchant name as stored in the lookup table.  You could use the same formula as above for that, but have the INDEX range point to column F instead of column G.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, for the sake of clarity on your last comment. I've been looking through Regex formulas for 3 days trying to find an answer but it's hard when you don't know the right question to ask. 

To ad further to your solution, is there a way to search the Merchant cell for "contains Nandos" but doesn't exactly match. So for example if the cell is: 

['7173 05APR17 CD NANDOS ROYAL FESTIVA GB]

It would still lookup and put "Food" as the category?

The Regex equivalent would be something like 

.*NANDOS.*

Comment: @JasonBroderick, that gets way more complicated.  The kind of thing that comes to mind would be iterating through the merchant list in the lookup table.  For each one, use a function like FIND to see if that merchant name appears anywhere in the merchant text in col A.  If you find a match, go back to the lookup table to get the category for that merchant.  With enough coffee, it might be doable with an array formula.  VBA would be another approach.

Comment: Hold on I just need to grab my Chinese dictionary. *Finds dictionary, uses it to smash window, jumps out of window.*

Comment: @JasonBroderick, OK, had to rise to the challenge.  See the expanded answer.  All the stuff about regex in the question would have made more sense if you had included the comment example (the question reads like a simple lookup, so it wasn't clear why you were referencing regex).  Does the expanded solution give you what you need?

Answer (score 1):

regex function :- `=INDEX($F$1:$F$4,MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH("*"&$E$1:$E$4&"*",E11)*ROW($E$1:$E$4),0)))`

after paste hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

[image: RegexFunctionExcelImage]

Comment: Clever.  Consider adding a few sentences of explanation.